# Messenger Extensions object only has {"AppleMusic":{}}

Tags: bots, facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm trying to make a messenger bot and chat extension.

1. I set the home_url
2. whitelisted the URL
3. Loaded the SDK correctly
4. doing everything inside `window.extAsyncInit`
5. And all the tests I'm doing are inside the messenger app in mobile.

But when I open the chat extension normally inside a chat thread and try to use,

```
getContext() or any other method
```

Nothing happens.

i.e.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.extAsyncInit = function () {
             MessengerExtensions.getContext('I pasted my app id here without quotes',
               function success(result){
                 alert("Success: "+result.psid);
               },
               function error(result){
                 alert(JSON.stringify(result));
               }
             );
         };
  </script>
```

and when I try to do this,

```
alert(JSON.stringify(MessengerExtensions))
```

it shows

```
{"AppleMusic":{}}
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Can you post the script tag your webview code?

Comment: I posted :) an edit